# Hyperledger Fabric API returns a buffer type data, how do i convert buffer to string of this data in javascript

Tags: javascript, buffer, hyperledger-fabric

i am building a blockchain on hyperledger fabric (node.js SDK).

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/global.html#BlockchainInfo__anchor

i call the api **BlockchainInfo** and get a **json** format response, which includes ***currentBlockHash***

the offical document shows that the response **data type** **of *currentBlockHash* is** **Array< byte >**

such as the following data.

i would like to convert this buffer to string but have no idea what to do.

thanks for your reading the question.

```
{ buffer:
   { type: 'Buffer',
     data:
      [ 8,
        207,
        230,
        17,
        18,
        32,
        124,
        143,
        73,
        40,
        171,
        42,
        251,
        237,
        193,
        138,
        36,
        92,
        58,
        57,
        254,
        56,
        144,
        96,
        54,
        201,
        242,
        64,
        10,
        111,
        150,
        28,
        198,
        187,
        196,
        118,
        97,
        160,
        26,
        32,
        16,
        160,
        154,
        19,
        11,
        179,
        147,
        11,
        38,
        16,
        150,
        190,
        126,
        17,
        121,
        123,
        200,
        7,
        71,
        27,
        241,
        103,
        54,
        188,
        196,
        248,
        178,
        88,
        48,
        115,
        186,
        133 ] },
  offset: 6,
  markedOffset: -1,
  limit: 38,
  littleEndian: true,
  noAssert: false }
```

here is the origin response data

```
{"height":{"low":291663,"high":0,"unsigned":true},"currentBlockHash":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[8,207,230,17,18,32,124,143,73,40,171,42,251,237,193,138,36,92,58,57,254,56,144,96,54,201,242,64,10,111,150,28,198,187,196,118,97,160,26,32,16,160,154,19,11,179,147,11,38,16,150,190,126,17,121,123,200,7,71,27,241,103,54,188,196,248,178,88,48,115,186,133]},"offset":6,"markedOffset":-1,"limit":38,"littleEndian":true,"noAssert":false},"previousBlockHash":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[8,207,230,17,18,32,124,143,73,40,171,42,251,237,193,138,36,92,58,57,254,56,144,96,54,201,242,64,10,111,150,28,198,187,196,118,97,160,26,32,16,160,154,19,11,179,147,11,38,16,150,190,126,17,121,123,200,7,71,27,241,103,54,188,196,248,178,88,48,115,186,133]},"offset":40,"markedOffset":-1,"limit":72,"littleEndian":true,"noAssert":false}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the JSDoc is misleading in this case. I think the `currentBlockHash` will actually be a Node.js Buffer (or possibly a protobuf implementation that emulates the behaviour of a Buffer). You can convert a Buffer into a string by calling `currentBlockHash.toString()`.

I have observed some cases where calling toString() on a protobuf Buffer implementation gives a debug string rather than a string representation of the content of the buffer so I tend to specify an encoding argument just to be safe.

In the case of a hash it may be more convenient to see it as a hex string rather than utf8 (which would be the default) anyway, so I would try `currentBlockHash.toString('hex')`

See here for more information on Buffers: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/buffer.html

Comment: i tried `currentBlockHash.toString('hex')` and get the string value.
Thank you very much